# When given 3 negative numbers, how can I ensure to always print the median of the 3 numbers entered (Intro C programming task)

Tags: c, median

So basically my C program task is to ask / allow user to enter 3 integers. Of the 3 integers entered, using a bunch of if / else statements I have to make sure it prints the median number of the 3.

For example, if user enters 4 5 6, then the median would be 5.

I have produced code which successfully manages to do this task except when I input the integers -2 -1 -3. The median is clearly -2 but instead prints out -1 as the median.

Below is my code;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int thirdNumber;

    printf("Please enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
    printf("PLease enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &secondNumber);
    printf("Please enter third number: ");
    scanf("%d", &thirdNumber);

    if (firstNumber < secondNumber && thirdNumber > secondNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", secondNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber < thirdNumber && secondNumber > thirdNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", thirdNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber > secondNumber && firstNumber < thirdNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", firstNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber > thirdNumber && thirdNumber < secondNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", secondNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber > secondNumber && secondNumber < thirdNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", thirdNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber > thirdNumber && secondNumber > firstNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", firstNumber);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have gone through each statement and I am still unsure as to why the final 
if statement is giving me problems.

I hope someone can assist me, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not related to negatives.  Try input `3 4 1`.

Comment: Hmmm, if all 3 numbers were the same, nothing would print.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? If so, you should accept the most valuable answer.

Answer (score 3):

This code is very bad. Anyway the first problem I saw was in the line

```
    } else if (firstNumber > thirdNumber && thirdNumber < secondNumber) {
    printf("The median is %d\n", secondNumber);
```

The conditions in `if` are not good to determine that `secondNumber` is median. You are only checking if `secondNumber` is greater than `thirdNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for you:

```
median = max(min(a,b), min(max(a,b),c));
```

---

Also you need to have `min` and `max` defined.

```
#define max(x, y)    (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define min(x, y)    (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two of your conditions were wrong. See modified conditions (marked with comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int thirdNumber;

    printf("Please enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
    printf("PLease enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &secondNumber);
    printf("Please enter third number: ");
    scanf("%d", &thirdNumber);

    if (firstNumber < secondNumber && thirdNumber > secondNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", secondNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber < thirdNumber && secondNumber > thirdNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", thirdNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber > secondNumber && firstNumber < thirdNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", firstNumber);
    } else if (firstNumber > thirdNumber && thirdNumber > secondNumber) {  // Changed this line
        printf("The median is %d\n", thirdNumber);        // Changed this line
    } else if (firstNumber > secondNumber && secondNumber > thirdNumber) {  // Changed this line
        printf("The median is %d\n", secondNumber);       // Changed this line
    } else if (firstNumber > thirdNumber && secondNumber > firstNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", firstNumber);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** The code doesn't work if two or all three numbers are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following logic-

```
    if(firstNumber > secondNumber && secondNumber > thirdNumber)
    printf("The Median is %d\n",secondNumber);
    else if(firstNumber < secondNumber && secondNumber < thirdNumber)
    printf("The Median is %d\n",secondNumber);
    else if(firstNumber > secondNumber && firstNumber < thirdNumber)
    printf("The Median is %d\n",firstNumber);
    else if(firstNumber < secondNumber && firstNumber > thirdNumber)
    printf("The Median is %d\n",firstNumber);
    else if(thirdNumber < secondNumber && thirdNumber > firstNumber)
    printf("The Median is %d\n",thirdNumber);
    else if(thirdNumber > secondNumber && thirdNumber < firstNumber)
    printf("The Median is %d\n",thirdNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers you entered satisfy the following condition

```
} else if (firstNumber > thirdNumber && thirdNumber < secondNumber) {
        printf("The median is %d\n", secondNumber);
```

Indeed both firstNumber and secondNumber are greater than thirdNumber.  However this condition does not determinate what is the median. It only determinates that two numbers are greater than a third number.

Moreover your code does not consider cases when some numbers can be equal each other.

To escape an error you should write all conditions in the form

```
a <= b && b <= c
```

where b obviously will be the median and substitute a, b, c for combinations of your variables.

So the code could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int thirdNumber;

    printf( "Please enter first number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &firstNumber );
    printf( "PLease enter second number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &secondNumber );
    printf( "Please enter third number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &thirdNumber );

    if ( firstNumber <= secondNumber && secondNumber <= thirdNumber )
    {
        printf( "The median is %d\n", secondNumber );
    }
    else if ( thirdNumber <= secondNumber && secondNumber <= firstNumber )
    {
        printf( "The median is %d\n", secondNumber );
    }
    else if ( thirdNumber <= firstNumber && firstNumber <= secondNumber )
    {
        printf( "The median is %d\n", firstNumber );
    }
    else if ( secondNumber <= firstNumber && firstNumber <= thirdNumber )
    {
        printf( "The median is %d\n", firstNumber );
    }
    else if ( firstNumber <= thirdNumber && thirdNumber <= secondNumber )
    {
        printf( "The median is %d\n", thirdNumber );
    }
    else if ( secondNumber <= thirdNumber && thirdNumber <= firstNumber )
    {
        printf( "The median is %d\n", thirdNumber );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you will enter -2 -1 -3 when the result will be

```
The median is -2
```